# Heroku SSL added but visiting domain still says connection is not private

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, dns

I use Heroku for deploying my app and I used GoDaddy to purchase my custom domain name and I purchased my SSL certificate from them.

Let's call my heroku hosted version of my application example-101.herokuapp.com
And let's call my custom domain I own mycustomdomain.com

I was trying to set up my GoDaddy purchased SSL certificate through heroku, and followed all of the steps here through step 7: 
http://www.joshwright.com/tips/setup-a-godaddy-ssl-certificate-on-heroku

Everything appears to be set up well. When I look in my Heroku GUI, at my settings for example-101.herokuapp.com, under 'Custom Domains' it lists **www.mycustomdomain.com** and **mycustomdomain.com**, each with DNS target **mycustomdomain.com.herokudns.com** and **www.mycustomdomain.com.herokudns.com** respectively.

When I run in the terminal:

```
curl -kvI https://www.mycustomdomain.com
```

the output says it "Connected", it "successfully set certificate verify locations", and after all the handshakes it says "SSL certificate verify ok."

**Now, here is where I'm afraid my problem may be.**

In GoDaddy, under my DNS Management for mycustomdomain.com, I followed heroku instructions by creating a new record as follows: 
Type: CNAME
Name: www
Value: example-101.herokuapp.com
TTL: 1 hour

But this was based on documentation that doesn't take into regard adding an SSL certificate.

When I run

```
heroku certs
```

it gives me the following: 
Name: brachiosaurus-94028
Common Names: www.mycustomdomain.com, mycustomdomain.com
Trusted: True
Type: SNI

**Should I be referencing brachiosaurus-94028 anywhere?**

When I actually try to visit www.mycustomdomain.com in my browser, the error it reads is NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID , and in the details, it says the Subject is  *.herokuapp.com
Is that the issue? That it's pointing to herokuapp.com when it should be pointing to herokussl.com or something of that nature?

If you have any insight on why this isn't working please let me know.

Also, I just set all of this up about an hour ago. Does it take a day or two before it it working properly and the browser recognizes the SSL certificate? Am I jumping the gun on asking for help?

Answer (score 11):

I contacted the heroku support, my problem was fixed.

1, set your CNAME correctly(I used the namecheap domains)
[image: namecheap screenshot]

2, after that, check that the heroku DNS target is the same as the namecheap host value.

[image: heroku screenshot]

3, restart the ACM (ssl)

[image: logs screenshot]

4, you need to wait for several minutes to check the website.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku has a new ssl implementation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

The asker appears to be using this new implementation. For this implementation, it's required to set the `CNAME` in your DNS Management as `mycustomdomain.com.herokudns.com`. You do not need to reference your certificate name, `brachiosaurus-94028` in your case.

Comment: but this contradicts the above answer... telling us to point the cname at the ssl dns name.

Answer (score 3):

When you add the SSL addon to Heroku, it generates a new domain, and you should use it as your CNAME value, and it's not the original herokuapp.com anymore. The `heroku certs` command should give you the domain you should use, which ending is `herokussl.com`

In your case, you probably should set the value of your CNAME as `brachiosaurus-94028.herokussl.com` (you can test the endpoint on your browser to see if it works).

It should not take so much time for it to work also (when I do this it is always instantly)

For more information check [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#subdomain)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was encountered because my DNS record specified app-name.herokuapp.com as the target for the CNAME rather than the provided DNS target. Update your DNS record to point at the correct DNS target.

To get the correct DNS target, run heroku domains in cli and it will show something like:

=== app-name Custom Domains
Domain Name       DNS Record Type DNS Target
api.myapp.io CNAME           powerful-tick-i29i319i39121321.herokudns.com